# Populate stack with deck of cards Java

Tags: java, arraylist, stack, push, peek

I am currently designing a java application that will perform many different operations on a shuffled deck of cards. Within the application I have:

- *Stack.java:*   This is the interface for the program, including methods like pop,push, peek
- *Deck.java:*    My deck class, which implements stack
- *Card.java:*    Card object class
- *Shuffle.java:* Contains the code to perform the riffle shuffle on the card
- *CardForce.java:* Main class

The cards within my program can be described as having a `face(A,2,3,4..J,K,Q)` a `suit(Hearts,Diamonds,Clubs,Spades)` and a value which corresponds to the face i.e
 `A = 1, 2 = 2, 3 = 3` and so on.

```
public Card(String cardFace, String cardSuit, int cardValue){
    face = cardFace;
    suit = cardSuit;
    value = cardValue;
}//ends Card
```

Currently I have my cards stored within an ArrayList within my deck class.

```
public class Deck implements Stack{


private List<Card> cards;

private int size;//number of cards in deck


public Deck(String[] faces, String[] suits, int[] values){
   cards = new ArrayList<Card>();
   for(String suit: suits) 
       for(int value = 0; value < values.length && value < faces.length; value++){
           Card a = new Card(faces[value], suit, values[value]);
           cards.add(a);
       }
   size = cards.size();
   //////////////////////////////////////shuffle();
   shuffle();
}//ends deck
```

I am looking to change my deck of cards from an arraylist to a stack, so I can perform the operations like pop, push & peek. Any help on how to implement those operations after the list has been converted to a stack is also welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add the stack functions to your Deck class and use the ArrayList as a stack.  Something like this:

```
public void push(Card c) {
  cards.add(c);
}

public Card pop() {
  Card c = cards.get(cards.size() - 1);
  cards.remove(cards.size() - 1);
  return c;
}

public Card peek() {
  return cards.get(cards.size() - 1);
}
```

You will need to add checks to `pop` and `peek` to make sure there are actually Cards in your deck, but this pretty much covers it.

Comment: Thanks mate! Just wondering how id call these methods in my main class now, quite new to java and cant figure out how to call non static variables.

Comment: In your main class you can create a new Deck object with `Deck d = new Deck(...)` and then call the methods like `d.push(new Card(...))`, `Card popped = d.pop()`, or `Card peeked = d.peek()`

Comment: Sorry to be a pain mate, but if were to say remove the top card of the deck, ask the user to specify the position within the deck where the card should be placed, then verify its in the correct position, how would i go about that?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `Stack` class in the JDK it will support those capabilities.

You can populate a `Stack` with an arraylist.

```
      List<Card> list = your array list
      Stack<Card> stack = new Stack<>();
      stack.addAll(list);
```